# Moving Camera To Position 3 if it is at Position 2 and keypressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so im new to C# and i was trying to code something that moved MainCamera to pos 2 if its in pos 1 and to pos 3 if in pos 2 but only if there if a keypress

KEYPRESS (in pos1)

V

Maincamera moves to pos2

V

KEYPRESS (in pos2)

V

Maincamera moves to pos3

```
public class CameraMove : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        public GameObject TargetPosition
          Targetposition.transform.position = new Vector3(106, 68, 15);
          Targetposition.transform.rotation = new Vector4(106, 68, 15);
          Targetposition.transform.position = new Vector5(106, 68, 15);
          Targetposition.transform.rotation = new Vector6(106, 68, 15);
          Targetposition.transform.position = new Vector7(106, 68, 15);
          Targetposition.transform.rotation = new Vector8(106, 68, 15);
          Targetposition.transform.position = new Vector9(106, 68, 15);
          Targetposition.transform.rotation = new Vector10(106, 68, 15);
    }

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
              Maincamera.transform.position=Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, #stack overflow messed up here, side and bottom lines of code are one# 
               Targetposition.transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

is as far as i could get

Comment: Your intentions seem clear enough, now please share any attempts you have made at solving the problem yourself so we can take a look at your approach.

Comment: done +Serlite but thats as far as i could get. C# i find confusing...

Comment: I haven't worked with Unity in about a year, but here are some thoughts. Put the three positions into the scene as GameObjects so you can use the editor to tweak position and angle, then you can `Lerp` or `Slerp` between both position and rotation. The rest are basic C# questions. Track which position is current, which position is the target, and use key-up to trigger movement to the next position. (I'd write a full answer, but I don't have time to load up Unity and test it and I've been away from that platform too long to be sure I'll get it right off the top of my head!)

Comment: Whenever a question starts off with "I'm new to C#" I recommend that you try to get comfortable with the language before moving onto something like Unity. At least get to the point where you don't say to yourself, "I'm a total newbie to C#".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have drafted up an answer that will work, but you will probably need to tweak it.

Firstly I use these variables

```
Vector3[] vecArray;
int changer;
float speed = 20f;
```

In your start you will fill vecArray with desired positions.

```
vecArray = new Vector3[] {new Vector3(2,40,90), new Vector3(60, 44, 29) , new Vector3(30, 9, 42) };
```

Now Update

```
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
    {
        changer++;
        if (changer >= vecArray.Length)
            changer = 0;

    }

    //If script is not attached the main camera will need to be found
    //Camera.main works if it is the main camera you are moving

    //first we will lerp toward object
    if (Vector3.Distance(vecArray[changer], transform.position) > .1)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position,
           vecArray[changer], speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }//snap when close to stop camera lerp if it cannot get exactly to position
    else
        transform.position = vecArray[changer];
```

This code will allow you to keep switching camera positions but that can easily change. To explain quickly whats happens. You change index by adding one each press. if it is greater than array length it goes back to zero. The lerp if is a quick solution and that hard coded .1 is to snap preventing bad lerp behavior. If your code gets more complex you can even use this code on a list. If you are still unsure of whats going on just add a comment.

Comment: Its worth adapting my answer with what McGuireV10 suggested, using a list rather than array (for flexibility).

Comment: Thanks JJMGsoftworks, i was wondering if something like this would work!

Comment: No problem, if you are new to c# and want to work with Unity I would recommend studying collections and proper use of objects. As you can see it will come in handy.